# Vim only highlights part of the python syntax

Tags: python, vim

I'm using the Vim editor to edit my python script on some remote clusters.I'm sure the Vim editors on both clusters have syntax highlight on. However, on one cluster I could see that all python keywords have been highlighted, while on the other one I could see only some of the python keywords are highlighted, and some keywords such as "range", "open" and "float" are not highlighted. Is there anything I can do in the .vimrc file such that all python keywords can be highlighted on that machine?

I don't know if this is related to the version of the Vim editor. On the machine that does not highlight all python keywords, the version of Vim is 7.2. While for the other machine, the version of Vim is 7.4.

Thanks.

Comment: Aside: "range", "open", and "float" are not Python [keywords](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords). They are, however, the names of [builtin functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#built-in-functions).

Comment: Have you tried the Vim docs?

Answer (score 3):

This has been solved by adding "let python_highlight_builtins=1" in the .vimrc file.